# Building apps with Android Studio failing - Unable to make field private static final java.util.Map

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception, build

I am new here and just started with Android Studio (Coursera Learning) and have continous problems to build and run the provided apps.

Setup:

- Windows 10
- Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2
- SDK Platform Packages: Android API 32; Android 11.0(R)
- Configured Environment Variable in Windows: JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_321
- Gradle JDK: C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17.0.2

I could successfully build and run the first provided app on a virtual device.

However, when I try to build and run the second app (which has just some extension to the first app) I get following error when building with the same setup:

**Unable to make field private static final java.util.Map java.lang.ProcessEnvironment.theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7dc36524**

[Failure Screenshot - same setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGJMW.png)

When I use the embedded JDK, I get following error:

**Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available**

[Failure description - different JDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN04C.png)

I really dont know what is the reason and why the apps behave differently, so I appreciate every hint or help. Thank you!

Comment: on which line of code does it not work?

Comment: The error does not specify. Source: also experiencing this issue. Log is : ```10:00:11 AM: Executing ':classes'...

10:00:11 AM: Execution finished ':classes'.```   

Then error

Answer (score 1):

Following the thread on: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc/issues/136
I updated gradle which solved both issues.
Remark: I sticked to my original JDK.